# Can't access model data from partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have to display some data to my partial view from my controller. I am already passing data to partial view but cant access from partial view. The error I am getting is actually saying something I missed. Please check the picture below for better understanding. Ask question if you don't understand anything.

[image: sample image]

[image: sample image]

_UserNav.cshtml:

```
@model User
<h2>@Model.FirstName</h2>
```

_Layout.cshtml:

```
if (this.User.IsInRole("User"))
                {
                    //@Html.Partial("_UserNav");

                    @Html.Action("_UserNav", "Dashboard", new { id = "test@gmail.com" });
                }
```

Controller:

```
[ChildActionOnly]
        public PartialViewResult _UserNav(string id)
        {
            using (mydb db = new mydb())
            {
                Models.User user = db.Users.Where(x => x.Email == id).FirstOrDefault();
                return PartialView("_UserNav", user);
            }
        }
```

Comment: I believe you need to provide fully qualified name with namespace for @model User

Comment: https://ibb.co/gvpVQR look used full name "Model.User" but still same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type declaration simply needs to be fully qualified.  Consider how your code files have things like this at the top of them:

```
using SomeNamespace;
using SomeNamespace.AnotherNamespace;
// etc.
```

These tell the compiler where to search for specific type names that you use in the code in that file.  Currently your view files don't have that.  If you're using older versions of MVC (before 5, I think) then you can add those directives to the `Web.config` in the Views folder:

```
<namespaces>
    <add namespace="SomeNamespace" />
    <add namespace="SomeNamespace.AnotherNamespace" />
    <!-- etc. -->
</namespaces>
```

For more recent versions you can put the directive in the view itself (at least, I'm pretty sure you can):

```
@using SomeNamespace
@using SomeNamespace.AnotherNamespace
```

Or, what's probably the **easiest** approach, in any and all versions of MVC/Razor/.NET/C#/whatever you can just fully-qualify the type:

```
@model SomeNamespace.AnotherNamespace.User
```

If I were to *guess* what your actual namespace might look like, it could be something like:

```
@model MvcApplication1.Models.User
```

But, of course, you'll have to check what the actual namespace is in your code.